# Netbeans error: Exception starting filter struts2 ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, struts2, classnotfoundexception

I have run the web application done using Struts. I not able to run the application I have faced the error while starting Apache tomcat errors and while run the web application it also throws error .I have post the error log below.

Error in starting Apache Tomcat server:

```
    Feb 04, 2016 3:19:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Error while running the web application:

```
 Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/Loyalty4Salon
OK - Undeployed application at context path /Loyalty4Salon
In-place deployment at /home/revathy/Documents/Esa netbeans/loyalty_salon/loyalty_salon/build/web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext2062383266810619779.xml&path=/Loyalty4Salon
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /Loyalty4Salon but context failed to start
/home/revathy/Documents/Esa netbeans/loyalty_salon/loyalty_salon/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1125: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

This is the `struts-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
    
    </form-beans>
    
    <global-exceptions>
    
    </global-exceptions>

    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
    </global-forwards>

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>
    
    <controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor"/>

    <message-resources parameter="com/myapp/struts/ApplicationResource"/>    
    
    <!-- ========================= Tiles plugin ===============================-->
    <!--
    This plugin initialize Tiles definition factory. This later can takes some
    parameters explained here after. The plugin first read parameters from
    web.xml, thenoverload them with parameters defined here. All parameters
    are optional.
    The plugin should be declared in each struts-config file.
    - definitions-config: (optional)
    Specify configuration file names. There can be several comma
    separated file names (default: ?? )
    - moduleAware: (optional - struts1.1)
    Specify if the Tiles definition factory is module aware. If true
    (default), there will be one factory for each Struts module.
    If false, there will be one common factory for all module. In this
    later case, it is still needed to declare one plugin per module.
    The factory will be initialized with parameters found in the first
    initialized plugin (generally the one associated with the default
    module).
    true : One factory per module. (default)
    false : one single shared factory for all modules
    - definitions-parser-validate: (optional)
    Specify if xml parser should validate the Tiles configuration file.
    true : validate. DTD should be specified in file header (default)
    false : no validation

    Paths found in Tiles definitions are relative to the main context.
    -->
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
        <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />      
        <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
    </plug-in>
    
    <!-- ========================= Validator plugin ================================= -->
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property
            property="pathnames"
            value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
    </plug-in>
  
</struts-config>
```

This is the `struts.xml`:

```
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result> 
        <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="c_cpnDetail"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="c_cpnDetail" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/cmpny_couponDetail.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="coupon_index"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="couponCode" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_create.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="createCoupon"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="create_Coupon" >
          
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>                  
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref> 
        <result name="invalid.token" type="redirect">coupon</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result> 
        <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/ImageFileUploadError.jsp</result>
    </action>  
  
    <!--<action name="couponAssignPage"
    class="com.Customer.Action"
     method="advSrch" > 
        <result name="success">./coupon_Assign.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">./error.jsp</result>
    </action> -->
   
    <action name="couponAssignPage"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="cpn_assignPage" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_Assign.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="cpn_getUsers"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="cpn_getUsers" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_Assign.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
    <action name="coupon_assign"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="assign_coupon" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
   
    <action name="couponAssign"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="coupon_assign"> 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="csvExport"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="csvExport"> 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/csvDownload.jsp</result>
      
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>        
    <action name="search_usr"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="srch_usr1" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_assign.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="deleteCoupon"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="dltCoupon" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="del_cpn"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="bulk_cpn_del" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="c_edit"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="editCouponretrieve" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_edit.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="editCoupon"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="editCoupon" > 
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>             
        <result name="success">/coupon_index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/ImageFileUploadError.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="couponSearchPage"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="couponSearchPage" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/Coupon_search.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
     
    <action name="couponSearch"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="coupon_search" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/coupon_searchResult.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
   
   
    <!-- Super Admin-->
    <action name="create_company"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="create_company" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_create.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="gen_key"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="couponCode" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_create.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_cmpnyDetail"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_cmpnyDetail" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpnyDetail.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_userDetail"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_userDetail" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpnyDetail.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="sa_createCmpny"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_createCmpny" > 
        <result name="invalid.token" type="redirect">sa_companyList</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/> 
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref> 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_companyList"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_listCmpny"> 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="sa_subCmpnyList"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_listSubCmpny" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_subcmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="sa_cmpny_status"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_cmpny_status" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_subcmpny_status"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_subcmpny_status" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_subcmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_cmpny_delete"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_cmpny_delete" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_subcmpny_delete"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_subcmpny_delete" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_subcmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_cmpny_editRetrieve"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_cmpny_editRetrieve" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_edit.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_subcmpny_editRetrieve"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_subcmpny_editRetrieve" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_subcmpny_edit.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_cmpny_edit"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_cmpny_edit" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="sa_cmpny_planedit"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_cmpny_planedit" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_cmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_subcmpny_edit"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_subcmpny_edit" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/sa_subcmpny_list.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action> 
    <action name="sa_login"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_login" > 
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/> 
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="invalid.token" type="redirect">/sa_login.jsp</result> 
        <result name="sa_success">/sa_start.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/start.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <!--<result name="graph">./Graph.jsp</result>-->
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action> 
   
    <action name="logout"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="logout" > 
        <result name="sa_success">/sa_start.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <!--<result name="success">/sample.jsp</result>-->
        <result name="Success">/start.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
    <action name="sa_logout"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="sa_logout">          
        <result name="success">/sa_login.jsp</result>           
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
    <action name="settings"
            class="com.Customer.Action"
            method="settings" > 
        <result name="success">/sa_start.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
    
    
    <!--REV SOURCE-->
    <!--Deals action result -->  
    <action name="importCsv" class="com.Customer.Action" method="importcsv">
        <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="wrong_csv">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
    </action>
              
    <action name="click_Deals"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="click_Deals" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
    <action name="addDeals"
            class="com.Customer.Deals"
            method="execute"> 
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>                    
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref> 
        <result name="invalid.token" type="redirect">click_Deals</result>
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/Deals_submit.jsp</result>
        <result name="reached-deals">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/ImageFileUploadError.jsp</result>
    </action>  
  
    <action name="addDeals_first"
            class="com.Customer.Deals"
            method="execute_list">
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/Deals_submit.jsp</result>
        <result name="reached-deals">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>    
 
 
    <action name="d_status"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="d_status" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="activate_deal"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="bulk_activate_deal" > 
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="inactivate_deal"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="bulk_inactivate_deal" >
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result> 
        <result name="success">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
   
   
    <action name="edit_Deal"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="edit_Deal">
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/Deals_edit.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
  
  
    <action name="editDealsData"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="edit_Deal_Data">                    
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>  
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/ImageFileUploadError.jsp</result>
    </action>
  
    <action name="Delete_Deal"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="Delete_Deal">
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="del_deal"
            class="com.Customer.Struts_Action"
            method="bulk_del_deal">
        <result name="logoutPage">/sa_login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/list_Deals.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
  
    
    

</struts>
```

Comment: It is S2 filter but S1 dtd. Which Struts are you using?

Comment: I think there are two struts file in the config folder...so i think we have used both s1 and s2.. can you help on this..i am new to struts..

Comment: Please refer this image ..

Comment: http://opentestdrive.com/demo/test/4.png,   http://opentestdrive.com/demo/test/3.png   http://opentestdrive.com/demo/test/2.png    http://opentestdrive.com/demo/test/1.png

Comment: waiting for a your help.......

Comment: can you see the image i have posted?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy Struts2 web application without Struts2 *core* libraries. The filter class declared in the `web.xml` can't be found on the classpath by web application classloader.

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- ... -->

</web-app>
```

How to resolve such issue. First you could try searching the internet for the class `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`. Even if the first result from Google points to [`web.xml`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/webxml.html) there's a lot of usable information but nothing about core libraries used by the framework. Ok, trying to search the class name on the [struts.apache.org](https://struts.apache.org) and it's giving the second result [Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html). It's created with Maven as a build tool. if you are not familiar with it you should read [maven.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/). In `pom.xml` it uses a dependency

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
>     <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
>     <version>X.X.X.X</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Of course replace the X.X.X.X with the current Struts 2 version. Maven
>   will get the struts2-core jar and the other jar files struts2-core
>   requires (transitive dependencies).

Netbeans has full support for Maven:

> NetBeans includes full Maven support since 6.7, including Maven 3 support in 7.0+. You can open any Maven project in the IDE and start coding immediately.
>
> For more information see the [NetBeans.org wiki page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven).

If you don't know how to find dependency for your project, you should read FAQ.

> [How to find dependencies on public Maven repositories?](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies)
>
> ```
> You could use the following search engines:
> ```
>
> - [http://search.maven.org](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies)
> - [http://repository.apache.org](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies)
> - [http://mvnrepository.com](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies)

Here you will find [search for `struts2-core`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.struts%22%20AND%20a%3A%22struts2-core%22) all required libraries depending on the version you need `2.3.12` I'd recommend the latest stable release at the moment [2.3.24.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.struts%7Cstruts2-core%7C2.3.24.1%7Cjar).

You can use Maven in your project to download required library and add them to dependencies. If you decide to manage your project dependencies manually you can get information about `struts2-core` dependencies on the maven site.

Comment: Hi i have added struts2-core2.3.24.1                                                                                                                                                                                                But it throws    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: i have added to libraries folder...is it necessary to add dependency? and how to add and link the jar file

Comment: you should download jar files and add them to war file in WEB-INF/lib. Either you do it manually or Netbeans can do it for you.

Comment: <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        
        <init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
    </filter>
    
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: there's no issue with the code but you can use above

Comment: but im still facing the issue of   SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: how to solve this..im new to struts

Comment: I did not add any dependency ...is the cause for the error?..i just copy the jar and paste it in library folder of the project

Comment: it's your problem that brings you to face the errors because you didn't follow this answer.